# Методы базовых классов Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Прошу не ругать за глупые вопросы, но ответа не нашел.
Где я могу посмотреть описание методов стандартных классов Laravel?
Например класс Controller.
В документации нашел только поверхностную инструкцию, а вот какие методы есть и что они делают - не нашел,

Comment: Только догадываться, много чего не документируется.

Comment: Зачем догадыватся. Лагавель прекрасно задокументирован

Comment: @ВадимАлександру и где тогда \то посмотреть? Есть ссылка?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel достаточно хорошо задокументирован и все публичные методы класса вы можете найти через Ctrl если вы в PHPStorm работаете. Так же желательно установить пакет ide-helper, который генерирует еще пару файлов для IDE, чтобы она лучше "ориентировалась".

Переходим к делу, если мы уже решили, что хотим знать все что под капотом некого функционала тогда у нас есть пару вариантов как это сделать.

1. Через xDebug, отследить все передвижение вашего запроса, там вы получите стектрейс всех загруженых классв, последовательность их выполнения итд.
2. Рефлексия, благо в PHP очень хорошее апи для работы с рефлексией. Вы можете на каком то этапе выполнения - словить экземпляр исследуемого класса, потом через рефлексию можете получить данные всех его полей\методов (даже приватных :D). Тут есть один момент, если класс, использует трейт `Macroable` тогда, скорее всего, доп функционал будет добавляться динамически к классу, т.к у этого трейта есть статическое поле `$macros` - массив из анонимных функций, которые потом юзают в маг методах __call() и __callStatic(). Это поле нужно отдельно исследовать.

При всем я все же не рекомендую лезть настолько глубоко или юзать незадокументированые методы (если конечно вы не желаете работать над самим Laravel, и внести свой вклад в развитие)

Ссылка на документацию
https://laravel.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Документация лары описывает часто используемое применение тех или иных компонентов системы.

И да, laravel под капотом использует много "магии".

Полный листинг компонентов фреймворка с классами, их методами, свойствами, трейтами, константами можно найти тут https://laravel.com/api/8.x/index.html

Comment: Очень хотелось бы узнать, какую магию вы там встретили?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру, магические методы `__call`, `__callStatic` используются во многих компонентах. Не магия ли?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я не совсем точно описал то, что мне надо.
Но вот та инфа, которую я искал: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/538402)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor спасибо, учту на будущее

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, вопрос - где найти документацию, ответ - ссылка на документацию - вроде всё к месту. Впрочем, сам вопрос по идее оффтопик.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я против таких ответов — ссылки в них могут просрочится и ценности в них не будет никакой. И характер вопроса здесь не имеет значение, на мой взгляд. Одной ссылкой отвечать не надо, надо самое главное суммировать, а если нельзя, то и ответ писать не надо, а вопрос — оффтоп.